# How to Paste object data to google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I paste the data (row and column) passed by the function `makeRequest` to google sheet.

I am retrieving the data from HTML storing that into an object and passing that object like this `makeRequest(facebookAccountData)`.

I can use something like this below to paste data (row and column) to sheet but in my case user will define which fields he requires. So I want to make this dynamic which I am not able do so.

```
   const imp = data.data[i]["clicks"];
   const clicks = data.data[i]["impressions"];
   const row = [imp,clicks];
```

**Code.gs**

```
function makeRequest(facebookAccountData) {
   
  
  // get API Service Service
  .. API Logic goes here.

  //set up the API Endpoint

  const base = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/';
  
  const endpoint = 'act_' +facebookAccountData.adAccount+ '/insights?' + '&fields=' + facebookAccountData.facebookFields + '&date_preset=' + facebookAccountData.startDate + '&level=ad'
  

  const url = base + endpoint;
  console.log(url);

  const params = {

    headers: {

      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
    }
    
  }
  
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
  console.log(response);

  const data = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log(data);

// CONSOLE DATA LOG RESULT

// { data: 
//    [ { campaign_name: 'XXX',
//        clicks: '25',
//        impressions: '765',
//        date_start: '2021-06-10',
//        date_stop: '2021-06-10' } ],
//   paging: { cursors: { before: 'MAZDZD', after: 'MAZDZD' } } }



pasteDataToSheet (data);
  
}

function pasteDataToSheet (data) {
  for (var i=0; i<data.data[0].length; i++) {
   const row = [dat.data[i]];
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(row);
    console.log(row);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification? I thought that when `setValues` is used instead of `appendRow`, the process cost will be able to be reduced a little. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

#### From:

```
pasteDataToSheet (data);
```

#### To:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const headers = Object.keys(data.data[0]);
const values = [headers, ...data.data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h]))];
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

#### Note:

- If you don't want to add the header row, please modify `const values = [headers, ...data.data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h]))];` to `const values = data.data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h]));`.
- In this modification, it supposes that the value of `data` is as follows.

  ```
    {
      data: [{
        campaign_name: 'XXX',
        clicks: '25',
        impressions: '765',
        date_start: '2021-06-10',
        date_stop: '2021-06-10'
      }],
      paging: { cursors: { before: 'MAZDZD', after: 'MAZDZD' } }
    }
  ```
- If you want to use the header of `["clicks", "impressions"]`, please modify `const headers = Object.keys(data.data[0]);` to `const headers = ["clicks", "impressions"];`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: @Arif Ahmed About your additional question of `Can you explain the o[h] part..`, in above script, `h` is each element of `header`. Using the header, the values are retrieved from the object of `{campaign_name: 'XXX',clicks: '25',impressions: '765',date_start: '2021-06-10',date_stop: '2021-06-10'}`. By this, the order of header is always same. If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: I have another question. When I run the query for the last 30 days, it pastes the data to the sheet which is all good. But when I run the query again, it pastes the data with the headers and rows again hence the header data is duplicated.  For instance, If I run the query for yesterday's date, it should paste headers and row with yesterday's data. And then if I run the query in today's data, it should only add a row with today's data.

Comment: @Arif Ahmed I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Yes offcourse. I can post a new issue and share it now within few minutes

Comment: Here is the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68014817/add-the-data-after-the-header-row-in-google-sheets

Comment: @Arif Ahmed Thank you for replying. I would like to check it. When I could find the solution, I would like to post the answer.