# Add the data after the header row in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am successfully able to retrieve data from an API and paste the data to the sheet. This works well.

Code.gs

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const headers = Object.keys(data.data[0]);
const values = [headers, ...data.data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h]))];
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

**This is the problem, I am facing:**

When I run the query or the function for the last 30 days, it pastes the data to the sheet which is all good. But when I run the query again, it pastes the data with the headers and rows again hence the header data is duplicated.

**What I want**

If I run the query for yesterday's date, it should paste headers and row with yesterday's data. And then if I run the query in today's date, it should only add a row with today's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
const values = [headers, ...data.data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h]))];
```

#### To:

```js
var values = data.data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h]));
if (sheet.getLastRow() == 0) values.unshift(headers);
```

- In this modification, by checking whether the 1st row is existing, the header row is added.